# ajax at once and at two

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(function(){

$('a.ajaxLink').click(function(e){
    var l = $(this).attr("href"),
    getdata;
    if(l != null){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
        url:l + '#book',

        success:function(result){

            getdata = $(result).find('#book');
            //$('#content').html(getdata);
            $('#content').fadeOut(function(){
                $('#book').remove();
                $('#content').append(getdata);
            });

                $('#content').fadeIn(function(){
                pos();
                });
        }
    });
    }
});

});
```

Hello, I have this code as above :) but there is a problem with the other files Loads multiple addresses with ajaxLink and then ajax does not work. It is something like this: the first click loads the partition with in the background the second click on a loaded by ajax page no longer works.

Comment: First of all, an attribute is never really `null`, if it's empty it's an empty string. Secondly, you're just adding a hash to the ajax URL, but the server doesn't read URL fragments, so God knows why, I'm guessing you're confused and think you can do the same thing as in `load()` to filter the result, but you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you replace the whole page or a part which contains your link, so the event bindning will no longer work. To make it work you should use jquery `on` function.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajaxLink', function(e){.... your handler goes here})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.on()` event handler rather than `.click()` because the `.on()` can handle new DOM elements but `.click()` dose not